# Boot USB ubuntu image from iPad?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, ipad

I know that you can run Ubuntu from a flash drive, booted from another machine. What I'm wondering is whether it's possible to boot such an image from an iPad (jailbroken or otherwise). I know that apple doesn't want you to use a usb drive, but I understand that it's possible to attach a usb drive using the usb camera adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been projects to get operating systems other then iOS installed on the iPhone, however, it's not as simple as putting a bootable image on a USB and connecting it to an iDevice.  For more information regarding this see:

- http://linuxoniphone.blogspot.com/
- http://linuxoniphone.blogspot.com/2010/04/ive-been-working-on-this-quietly-in.html
- http://code.google.com/p/iphone-linux/
- http://twitter.com/#!/planetbeing

There seems to have been a lull in development lately.  The short answer to your question is that currently it's not possible to boot a Linux image from an iPad/iPhone.