# Installing Ubuntu on iPad 1?

Tags: system-installation, ipad

So, I might be getting an old iPad 1 to tinker with and had been doing my daily Question/Answer reviews and came across this question: [How can I install Ubuntu on an iPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-ipad).

The device is so old I doubt it would run many official App Store apps, so I thought I would give Ubuntu a try. Does anyone know if this is feasible today?

I would want to know if it is doable, useable, and legal (kind of confused as of this: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9232937/iPhone_jailbreaking_still_legal_in_US_but_don_39_t_meddle_with_an_iPad?source=CTWNLE_nlt_dailyam_2012-10-26)

I looked at the iDroid project page and it looks like the iPad 1 has been cracked enough to provide CPU control, but I'm really can't figure out the chart: http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Status#iPad

While getting Ubuntu desktop to work on the iPad would be a fun project, getting Ubuntu Touch would also be fun. If anyone has any links/sites regarding the iPad 1 running Ubuntu Touch, those would also be great. I know there isn't an official build of Ubuntu Touch, just the Google Nexus devices are supported that way.

This would be a sweet summer project, so if anyone knows of any sites that have this working, that would be stupendous!

Comment: No one had been able to do that as of two years ago as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/30509/boot-usb-ubuntu-image-from-ipad/30510#30510 - good luck!